# Parse XML file using Python. multiple hierarchies

Tags: python, xml

I want to parse the following xml file using python. My "folder" variable is set up to always equal the 8-digit number towards the end of the `<link>` tag. In this case it is 11119709.

Python

```
for folder in folderList:
```

I want to be able to say, when "folder" equals the last 8 digits in the link tag, give me what the eq:seconds value is. I tried playing with the code provided by python docs element tree, but I am having trouble with it because there are so many hierarchies. root[0][1].text will not retrieve variables under the item tag.

XML

```
-<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/" xmlns:eq="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/rss/1.0/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"   xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" version="2.0">
  -<channel>
      <title>USGS Earthquake ShakeMaps</title>
      <description>List of ShakeMaps for events in the last 30 days</description>
      <link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/</link>
      <dc:publisher>U.S. Geological Survey</dc:publisher>
      <pubDate>Thu, 27 Mar 2014 15:33:05 +0000</pubDate>
      <item>
         <title>4.11 - 79.3 miles NNW of Kotzebue</title>
         <description>
         <![CDATA[<img src="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/shakemap/thumbs/shakemap_ak_11199709.jpg" width="100" align="left" hspace="10"/><p>Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 07:28:31 UTC<br/>Lat/Lon: 67.9858/-163.494<br/>Depth: 15.9122</p>]]></description>
         <link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/shakemap/ak/shake/11199709/</link>
         <pubDate>Thu, 27 Mar 2014 07:53:33 +0000</pubDate>
         <geo:lat>67.9858</geo:lat>
         <geo:long>-163.494</geo:long>
         <dc:subject>4</dc:subject>
         <eq:seconds>1395905311</eq:seconds>
         <eq:depth>15.9122</eq:depth>
         <eq:region>ak</eq:region>
         </item>
       <item>
              ...similar to above item
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about speed, I recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/). It has extra dependencies but is usually much faster than BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which can parse HTML and XML (with an external module) and is way easier to use than the one included in Python.

This code should do what you want :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = BeautifulSoup(open("filename.xml")) # here you load your XML file
# you can also load it from an URL by using "urllib" or "Python-Requests"

# BeautifulSoup(open("filename.xml"), "xml") # if you want to use an XML parser
# see comments below

for folder in folderList:
    for item in xml.findAll("items"): # iterate through all <item> elements
        if folder in item.link.text: # if folder's name is in the <link> element
            print(item.find("eq:seconds").text) # print the <eq:seconds> element
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure I can install beautifulsoup on our server machine but I will look into it.

Comment: @Andrew If you have access to a shell (for example via SSH) you can easily install it with PIP : `pip install beautifulsoup4`, and if you don't have PIP you can extract the beautifulsoup tarball in your script's directory.

Comment: BeautifulSoupt is _not_ an xml parser, but it can use `lxml` for parsing xml. But to do so you need to pass the [`"xml"` argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to the constructor. Otherwise the content it's parsed using a html parser and not as xml!

Comment: @mata updated my answer - but personally I never had any issues with parsing XML with BS4's HTML parser.

Comment: It's a question of what you want. The html parser happyly parses invalid xml, which usually isn't what you want. The xml parser throws an exception. Also - depending on the used parser - it may wrap the xml in `<html></html>` tags...

Comment: @mata here I suppose that the author cares more about the content rather than the validity of the XML so the HTML parser should do the trick.